# How can I make a tabBar element for random content?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native project where I publish a book with chapters and sections. My app works fine with the chapter listings, section listings and all. But I want to add a new screen for a random reading topic.

I am using react-navigation.

Every time user presses Random tab, I want to show another random section there.

Right now, when users press the Random tab, a random post is generated. Then users visit another tab and come back, another random post is generated. But I want users to be able to generate random post without having to visit another tab. Press Random, one random post generated. Press Random and one more random post again.

See the picture, if users press `Rastgele` button respectively, I want my component to refresh every time so they get a random piece to read without having to visit another tab for random feature to work.

[image: Random-Button-Tab-Bar]

I could not wrap my head around this since last night. I would appreciate any help.

Here is what my code looks like right now.

App.js

```
const BookStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Chapter: { screen: ChapterScreen },
    Section: { screen: SectionScreen }
  });

const RandomStack = createStackNavigator({
    Random: { screen: RandomScreen }
  });

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
  });

const App = createAppContainer(
  createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Ilmihal: BookStack,
      Rastgele: RandomStack,
      Ayarlar: SettingsStack
    },
    {
      defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        //Icon rendering here
      }),
      tabBarOptions: {
      resetOnBlur: true,
      lazy: false
    }
  )
);
```

RandomScreen.js

```
const RandomScreen = () => {
  //sectionTitle, sectionContent, pageTitle generated here

  return (
    <Content>
      <Text>{sectionTitle}</Text>
      {sectionContent.map( (p, index) => <Text key={index}>{p}</Text> )}
    </Content>
  );
};

RandomScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    headerTitle: () => (
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}>{pageTitle}</Text>
    )
  };
};
```

Comment: Can u share a gif of what u got and what u want to achieve?

Comment: I added a screenshot to post.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, right now of what i understood, your screen triggers your `RandomScreen` function everytime you pass from a tab to the `Rastgele` tab. The problem is that you want to trigger the random tab also if the screen is already in focus.

You can try using the `tabBarOnPress` function inside your `RandomScreen` component:

```
RandomScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
 return {
    headerTitle: () => (
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}>{pageTitle}</Text>
    ),
    tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) =>{
       //Do what you need for your RandomScreen
       defaultHandler();
    } 
  };
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Hey, did you try it out?

Comment: Sorry I got a new computer and it took a while to reconfigure react-native expo stuff back to normal. It's a little late but I finally had a chance to try. Seems like the function in `tabBarOnPress` is not triggered when I press the button. There is a `<NavigationEvents />` component built in `react-navigation` I will try to fix it with that.